# How to get autocomplete data correctly formatted

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net, autocomplete

Using .NET here's what I've got.. The right results are returned, but they're all combined together into one long string. How can I make it so I can select one item at a time from the results returned? I know my source in the javascript is configured incorrectly. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Code behind:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
public static string[] GetEmails(string emailContains)
{
    LoginSet logins = staticLogic.searchLogins(staticClient, new SearchCriteriaSet());

    List<BaseEntry> loginList = logins.Where(x => ((LoginEntry)x).LoginEMail.Contains(emailContains)).ToList();

    List<string> emails = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < loginList.Count(); ++i)
    {
        string email = ((LoginEntry)loginList.ElementAt(i)).LoginEMail;
        emails.Add(email);
    }

    //JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    //string json = serializer.Serialize(emails.ToArray());

    return emails.ToArray();
}
```

UI:

```
<tr><td>Destination:</td>
    <td>
        <div class="ui-widget">
            <input type="text" name="EMailReportDestination" id="EMailReportDestination" size="60" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

JQuery:

```
        $('#EMailReportDestination').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/reports/editemailreport.aspx/GetEmails',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: "{'emailContains':'" + request.term + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },

                    success: function (data) {
                        //console.log('autocomplete success: ' + data);
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item,
                                value: item
                            }
                        }));
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        console.log("autocomplete error: " + xhr.status + ", " + thrownError);
                    }
                });

            },
            minLength: 2,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                console.log(ui.item ? "selected: " + ui.item.label : "nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
            },
            open: function () {
                $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
            },
            close: function () {
                $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried and I don't know array returned in data.d. try to change

```
response($.map(data, function (item)
```

to

```
 response($.map(data.d, function (item)
```

Comment: Also you can read this article
[link](http://encosia.com/never-worry-about-asp-net-ajaxs-d-again)